# Paracompact and Compactly Generated spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness, paracompactness

A couple of days ago, thanks to Strom's excellent book *Modern Classical Homotopy Theory*, I started reading up on compactly generated spaces, weak Hausdorff spaces and compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces (the **best decision in my life** so far). The classical article by Steenrod *A Convenient Category of Topological Spaces* and Strickland's openly available exposition *The Category of CGWH Spaces* have been extremely valuable resources.

Not only have these texts shown me there is a conceptually satisfying way to deal with the topology in algebraic topology without any funny business, but for the first time ever, I understand the importance of the categorical viewpoint (and Yoneda's lemma).

I have several times tried to grasp algebraic topology in the past, and have gone some way each time, however I was always held back by the topology, and have come to StackExchange on a couple occasions to ask questions. I learnt about classifying spaces for vector bundles and principal bundles and thus know of the usefulness of paracompact spaces, so I want to know wether my new paradise (the category of CGWH spaces) contains them.

> 1) Are paracompact (resp. regular, normal...) spaces compactly generated?
>
> 1') Are paracompact (resp. regular, normal...) Hausdorff spaces compactly generated?
>
> 2) If not, is the $k$-ification of a paracompact (resp. regular, normal...) space still paracompact (resp. regular, normal...)?
>
> 3) Are there free online resources that give a **thorough** account of paracompactness and other such separation properties (such as regularity, normality, metrizability) and their interplay?

The article on nLab linked me to a set of lecture notes I have thus far only saved on my pc (http://www.helsinki.fi/~hjkjunni/ the top.$1$ to top.$10$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to all versions of (1) and (1') is *no*.

Let $D$ be an uncountable set and $p$ a point not in $D$. Let $X=\{p\}\cup D$, and topologize $X$ by making each point of $D$ isolated and making $V\subseteq X$ a nbhd of $p$ iff $p\in V$ and $X\setminus V$ is countable. In other words, if $\tau$ is the topology on $X$, $$\tau=\wp(D)\cup\{X\setminus C:C\subseteq D\text{ and }|C|\le\omega\}\;.$$

($X$ has been called the *one-point Lindelöfization* of the uncountable discrete space $D$.)

$X$ is easily seen to be paracompact, Hausdorff, and hereditarily normal, but $X$ is not a $k$-space: the only compact subsets of $X$ are the finite subsets, and they don’t generate the topology.

The $k$-ification of a Hausdorff space is certainly Hausdorff, since the new topology is finer than the original one; I don’t know about the other properties off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you for that counter-example! I think it shows us that the $k$-ification of a paracompact space need not be paracompact. Indeed, the only compact subspaces of $X$ are the finite ones, and a subset $O\subset X$ is $k$-open iff for any compact subset $K$ of $X$, $K\cap O$ is open in $K$: since $K$ is discrete, this places no restriction on $K\cap O$, so $k\tau$ is the discrete topology on $X$, which is not paracompact because $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: @Olivier: The discrete topology on any set is paracompact: every open cover even has a discrete open refinement, which is certainly locally finite. The cardinality doesn’t matter.

Comment: ohhhhh! I was thinking of countable covers. You are right!